# Java distributed architecture and versioning

Tags: java, versioning, distributed

I have a enterprise distributed n-tier architecture written in Java 1.4 (EJB and Web-application).

I have a new business requirement: the enterprise service would handle the versioning. At first I found that the OSGi service model.

Is there any alternative to this model?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  That's a fairly broad requirement

Answer (score 1):

OSGi addresses the loading of dependent modules, allowing the versions of these to be controlled. I don't believe that it addresses distributed environments.

Versioning in distributed systems is a wide ranging problem. You need to tie down exactly what youa re being asked to do. For example do you need to support parallel running of different versions of a remotely called EJB? This is possible but may require some care. Sometimes folks introduce ESBs to enable transformation between clients expecting one version of a service and implementations offereing a different version.

I suggest you explain exactly what you are being asked to do.